# Upladed images from iOS app bad rotation

Tags: php, ios, image, rotation, server

when I upload image from my iOS app to server and show it on website, it's sometimes badly rotated. I've found that its done by EXIF image metadata, but I have no idea how to solve it. Can someone help me, please? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following category for fixing the rotation issues

**UIImage + OrientationFix.h**

```
@interface UIImage (OrientationFix)
- (UIImage *)fixOrientation;
@end
```

**UIImage + OrientationFix.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (OrientationFix)

- (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

    // No-op if the orientation is already correct
    if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

    // We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
    // We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            break;
    }

    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;

        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            break;
    }

    // Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
    // calculated above.
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                             CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
    switch (self.imageOrientation) {
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
            // Grr...
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
            break;

        default:
            CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
            break;
    }

    // And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
    CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
    return img;
}

@end
```

**Usage**

```
[<YOUR_UIIMAGE> fixOrientation];
```

https://gist.github.com/alex-cellcity/1531596